# Не работает EmailMultiAlternatives django

Tags: python, django, ssl, smtp

Есть такой код в views.py.
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
template_name = 'post/add.html'
form_class = PostForm
permission_required = ('NewsPortal.add_post',)
success_url = reverse_lazy('created')

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('created', kwargs={'pk': self.object.id})
```

class PostSuccessfullyView(DetailView):
template_name = 'post/created.html'
model = Post

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    user = self.request.user
    email = user.email
    header_field = self.object.header_field
    # print(f'user: {user}')
    # print(f'email: {email}')
    # print(f'header_field: {header_field}')

    html = render_to_string('post/created.html',
                            {'header_field': header_field,
                             'user': user
                             }
                            )
    print(html)
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
        subject=f'{header_field} subscription',
        body='',
        from_email='khegaivyacheslavA@yandex.ru',
        to=['khegaivyacheslavA@yandex.ru']
    )
    msg.attach_alternative(html, "text/html")
    try:
        msg.send()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return context
```

Логика такая, когда пользователь создает новый пост, его перекидывает на страницу успешно созданного поста, и все кто подписан на данную категорию должны получить письмо на почту, но даже с учетом того, что я ставлю получателем ту же почту, что и делает рассылку, выходит ошибка. Использую яндекс smtp, в settings все прописано верно, подскажите как решить. Я вот грешу может на macOS у меня сертификаты не подходят или не обновлены?

```
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)
```